# vue.js can't see my variables

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4

I am new to vue.js and I am having a little challenge. 
I create a file ChatMessage.vue and this is the content of the file.

```
<template>
<div>
     <p>{{message}}</p>
    <small>view author here</small>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'chat-message',
    data () {
        return {
            message: 'message',
            user: "John Ham"
        }
    }
}
</script>

<script lang="css">
</script>
```

I get this error message when I try to run.

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the 
instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive 
data properties in the data option.

found in

---> <ChatMessage> at 
/var/www/html/..../resources/assets/js/components/ChatMessage.vue
   <Root>
```

I have this in my laravel blade template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chatroom</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <h1>Chatroom</h1>
    <chat-message></chat-message>

</div>
<script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-
token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my app.js, I have this

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('chat-message', 
require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: `<script lang="css"></script>` what is it?

Comment: In my case I forgot to reference the component variable, e.g. using `this. message `

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is syntax related for some reason, I have to include

```
<script lang="css"></script>
```

before

```
<script>
export default {
 name: 'chat-message',
 data () {
    return {
        message: 'message',
        user: "John Ham"
     }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your css should be in `<style>` tags, not `<script>` tags. See [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

Comment: Yes, I later found out I can do that. Thank you very much @Roy J

Answer (score 0):

This could be taking place because of a 'wrongly dated script'.
You have got to know the latest version of Vue.js out there and use the correct script according to your project.

As of the time of this response:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

is the correct script for Vue 3.

However you can check the https://unpkg.com/ page in order to see what is the latest script out there, or test out the best fit for the node version you have gotten on your machine.

Also, here's my current project folders structure

```
.
├── app
│   ├── index.html
└── src
│   └── app.js
```

My code

*index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello Vue</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="src/app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>My name is: {{ name }}</p>
        <p>This is just a {{ title }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*app.js*

```js
const MyNameApp = {
    data() {
        return {
            name: "Kolis",
            title: "F***ING TEST"
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(MyNameApp).mount("#app");
```

Peace!